# Roots of polynomials modulo prime powers

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

I'm reading the paper

Dearden, Bruce(1-ND); Metzger, Jerry, Roots of polynomials modulo prime powers. 
European J. Combin.  18  (1997),  no. 6, 601–606.

link: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0195669896901249

In the last section the authors state

"If $t$ is a root of a polynomial modulo $p$. then $t$ yiels either no roots modulo $p^2$, or a single root $t+kp$ modulo $p^2 (k=0, \ldots, p-1)$, or else the roots $\{t+kp\;\:\;k=0,\ldots, p-1\}$ modulo $p^2$."

(The polynomial are in $\mathbb Z[x]$ and $p$ is a prime number)

I do not understand this statement. I think it has something to do with the Hensel lemma.

Someone can help me to understand the statement?

Comment: Can you put a link to that paper?

Comment: Yes. Hensel's Lemma essentially says that $t$ gives a unique root mod $p^2$ provided $f'(t)\ne0\bmod p$. Consider for example, the polynomial $x^2$. That gives $p$ roots mod $p^2$, which is one reason you need $f'(t)\ne0\bmod p$. What is the difficulty exactly?

Comment: The authors in the statement claim that for a root $t$ modulo $p$ we have: 1) no roots modulo $p^2$; 2) a single root $t+kp$ modulo $p^2$; 3) $p$ roots $\{t+kp\;\;k=0, \ldots, p-1\}$. If $f^ \prime(t)\neq 0$, then from Hensel lemma we have 2). But if $f^ \prime(t)= 0$ when we have 1) and when we have 3)?

Comment: If $f'(t)\equiv0\pmod{p}$ and $t$ is a solution modulo $p^2$, then $t+kp$ is a solution modulo $p^2$ for all $k$. If $t$ is not a solution modulo $p^2$, then none of the $t+kp$ are either. This is because
$$f(t+kp)\equiv f(t)+kpf'(t)\pmod{p^2}$$ by Taylor expansion. So if here $f'(t)$ is divisible by $p$, then
$$f(t+kp)\equiv f(t)\pmod{p^2}$$ for all $k$.